# Can't change the background on mouse click

Tags: javascript, background-color, p5.js

***Hello i cannot make the background color change when I click with the mouse anywhere, I would like to change the background when clicking on the buttons, but anywhere in the screen if fine.
I'm using P5***

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfv12.png)

Comment: Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Do not post screenshots of the code. Paste the code.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (and get a badge). Your question lacks any attempt at solving this problem on your own. The idea is for you to try to get something to work and then come here with specific problems you are unable to resolve. Taking the tour and reading about [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center will provide all the information you need.

Comment: your question is not clear enough

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

**Click "Run Code Snippet" to view result.**

```js
function draw() {
  background(220);
  ellipse(50,50,80,80);
  
   if (mouseIsPressed) {
    fill(225,142,150);
  } else {
    fill(255);
  }
  
 
}


function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```